# Code Flow Guard on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, gcc, malware

In the Windows, Visual Studio compiler just introduced Code Flow Guard, which documents all possible jump/call locations and crashes if you were to jump to the middle of a function. Is there any way to achieve the same effect with GCC?

Probably 99% of apache, openssh, postfix/dovecot servers are compiled with default settings. I was thinking of simple compiler checks requiring no code change that would detect basic 0-days being used against my server.

Comment: Is Information Security where a curious individual like me might ask if the sense of security provided by this feature is a false one?

Comment: Well, there's always going to be other vectors outside your control. I'm just trying to minimize the automated script-kiddie crap from easily hacking your system through known exploits or unpatched exploits.

Comment: Oh, my comment wasn't meant as a critique on the question at all.  From a quick glance at the MSDN page, it appears that this is also a feature of the Windows _kernel_, so Linux itself would also have to support it, not just the compiler.  It's still really neat!

Comment: @Fox call target validation can drastically reduce the expressiveness of [Return-Orientated Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) attacks. While it alone doesn't prevent an attack from exploiting memory corruption vulnerabilities, it may hinder them from gaining arbitrary code execution capabilities.

Comment: @user3716714 Are you only interested in GCC or would answers addressing [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SafeStack.html) be acceptable?

Comment: Yeah if another compiler like clang could achieve it, that'd be acceptable too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probly looking for [CFI](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ControlFlowIntegrity.html) which appeared in recent Clang. Note that SafeStack (suggested in comments) is something different.